# Compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ where $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{50}{x}+\frac{20}{y}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, fractions

> Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$
>   $$f(x,y)=xy+\frac{50}{x}+\frac{20}{y}.$$ Compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and find local extrema of the function $f$.

I'm having difficulties solving this task. May I ask for help? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What do you have to do?

Comment: i need to know the partial derivatives of x,y to find local extrema of (f) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is calculated by thinking that $y$ is a constant. Therefore you have
$$
\frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial x}} = y - \frac{{50}}
{{x^2 }}
$$
The partial derivative with respect to $y$ is calculated by thinking that $x$ is a constant. Therefore you have
$$
\frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial y}} = x - \frac{{20}} 
{{y^2 }}
$$

Comment: ok, i understand but (-) become (+) because x will be squared? and sorry, my bad, it was 20/y not 20y.

Comment: Use $\frac{d}{dx}\frac1x=-\frac1{x^2}$.